# How can I consume IIS7's FREB programatically

Tags: iis-7, web-server, web, trace

[I'm replicating a question I put on Stack Overflow a while ago and received no answer - figuring that it's more up Server Fault's alley (SF didn't exist yet when I first posted this)]

IIS 7 has a very useful feature called [Failed Request Tracing](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/dunnry/Failed-Request-Tracing-on-IIS7/#356252) (FREB for short). It has a very nice visualization feature, involving an extremely complex XSL stylsheet that parses the results into a useful treeview.

I, however, want to consume FREB programatically, and be able to present the results on my smart client (without waiting for the XML to be written server-side).

The only possible solution I found so far, involves compiling an IIS7 C++ plugin that converts FREB into OutputDebugStrings, an approach even the writer suggets should not be used on a production server ([here's the article](http://blogs.iis.net/rickjames/archive/2007/10/10/iis-7-c-module-api-sample-consuming-trace-events.aspx))

My question is: is there another approach?

As always, my thanks for reading, and even more for replying.
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielvl/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-consume-etw-events-from-c.aspx) on consuming ETW events? I believe you could change the GUID in the sample to the Trace Provider GUID ({0x528dbd54,0x1b68,0x4f58,{0xa8,0xc0,0xb3,0x92,0xdf,0x6d,0xf0,0xc9}}). Another article worth looking at is [this one](http://blogs.iis.net/eokim/archive/2009/05/15/consume-iis-etw-tracing.aspx) on hooking into the trace via c++ (different than the article you linked).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - completely forgot about the ETW roots of FREB. Will give it a try.